# Use of %%cmd in ipython notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have a simple question about use of cmd magic in iPython notebook.

I am running the following code in iPython notebook in Windows 7:

```
%%cmd 
cd "C:\djangosite" 
python manage.py runserver
```

However, this brings up `C:\djangosite>More?` rather than running the python code as expected.  It seems that the `python` command is running, but it's somehow not passing the `manage.py runserver`

Thanks very much for any help,

Robin